# How to setup proper scope inside Jasmine spyOn method call?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am currently trying to test if I am able to call certain methods in a class I built. Through trial and error I was able to get it to connect with the class properly but now I am getting this error:

"Error:  : could not find an object to spy upon for sayHello()"

After researching I believe this to be a scope issue. I have tried removing removing bookTitles within the spyOn call, adding prototype to fakeTitle (and its corresponding parts), as well as messing about with the method declarations inside the class in my main JS file. None of those tries seemed to have worked (in fact it actually broke the link half the time). Why is the spyOn method not able to recognize sayHello()?

Here is my code:

```
class bookTitle {
    helloSomeone(toGreet) {
        return this.sayHello() + ' ' + toGreet;
    }

    sayHello() {
        return 'Hello';
    }
}

module.exports = {
    bookTitle
}
```

and my Jasmine file:

```
var bookTitles = require ('./bookTitles.js');

describe('bookTitle', function() {
    it('calls the sayHello() function', function() {
        var fakeTitle = new bookTitles.bookTitle();
        spyOn(bookTitles.fakeTitle, 'sayHello');
        bookTitles.fakeTitle.helloSomeone('world');
        expect(bookTitles.fakeTitle.sayHello).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Also a side question, if I am saying the fakeTitle object is part of the bookTitle class then why do I need to declare bookTitles within the spyOn method and below? My thought process is that by saying its a new object within the class of the required file then shouldn't any method calls after that automatically assume that is where the call is supposed to go to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to spy on the object you created:

```
describe('bookTitle', function() {
    it('calls the sayHello() function', function() {
        var fakeTitle = new bookTitles.bookTitle();
        spyOn(fakeTitle, 'sayHello');
        fakeTitle.helloSomeone('world');
        expect(fakeTitle.sayHello).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})
```

Comment: I see, I was conceptually misunderstanding how spyOn functions. This answer also simultaneously answers my side question, thank you for the help!